# How to position a UIToolbar in a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've a sample project, where I have created a custom *UIWebView* named *WebView*. They are added to the view in a *UIViewController*. Two *WebView*'s are initialized in the *viewDidLoad* and added to an array list. The first one is added as subview på *self.view*. The Storyboard contains a UIBarButton, and when this is tapped, the second *WebView* is added as subview to the *self.view*.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WebView *webView1 = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    WebView *webView2 = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.webViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: webView1, webView2, nil];

    UIWebView *webView = [self.webViews objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.google.com/"]]];
}
```

Here is the implementation of the *WebView* where a toolbar is added to the bottom (-50px) of the view:

```
@implementation WebView

- (void) initToolbar {
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height-80, 320, 30);

    [self addSubview:toolbar];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self initToolbar];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The problem is, that the toolbar does not have the same position in the two views (they could be positioned like the first one). Why are they not positioned equally?

You can download the small sample project here:
http://uploads.demaweb.dk/UIWebView.zip

**My notes:** As mentioned, the two *WebView*'s are currently initialized in the *viewDidLoad*. If I instead wait and first initialize then when I need them, it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that `self.frame.size.height` on `viewDidLoad` is not the same when you initialize it via the button click. If you add the `UIWebView` directly in `viewDidLoad`, the `UINavigationBar` of your `UINavigationController` is not loaded yet and the frame of `self.view` is 'perceived' to be (not really, because it **is**) larger.

This explains the difference of 40.0 (?) points.

One possible solution to this problematic behaviour is to initialize and add (at least the first) instance of `UIWebView` in the `viewWillAppear:animated` method. (`UIViewController` does already implement this method)